# retrieving special characters from mysql database, php

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding, mysqli

I've inserted some data to a mysql database. Set up the utf-8 cz. And it looks fine.
[image]

But when I echo a row from the table, special characters are not shown. Meta utf-8 included.
[image]

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Is your page generating utf-8 encoded output? If your webserver encoding defaults to other codepage, it's the way browser interprets it, rather than mysql issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

before you execute the query in PHP

Answer (score 0):

add this too your  too to ensure browser's read your page with the right encoding:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```